# Can I merge permissions of delegated GraphServiceClient and application GraphServiceClient?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to implement a search algorithm for our people using Microsoft Graph. What I would like to do is have 1 (not 2) instance of `GraphServiceClient` and use that to query People. Then, if no search results come up, I query the Users.

Currently, I use the *delegated* `GraphServiceClient` instance to use the [people search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/people-example#search-people), and I use the other *application* `GraphServiceClient` to [search Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter). But when I try to use the *delegated* GraphServiceClient to search Users, it gives me an unauthorized error.

Both use the same App ID registered into Microsoft so why can't I just have one instance instead of having 2 different instances? I've already received admin permissions to read our users. I just want to have 1 instance of Microsoft Graph. Not 2.

Edit: Here's the error message I get when trying to query users using a *delegated* GraphServiceClient instance:

> Code: Authorization_RequestDenied\nMessage: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.\n\nInner error\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. I just requested `Directory.Read.All` permissions from the user and I was able to access the list of Users to perform my search.

I don't even need application permissions anymore!